# Expanding a function with trigonometric expressions in a controlled manner by excluding addition identities

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I want to simplify a nonlinear equation with trigonometric terms. After I've expanded I don't want to loose open terms to Trigonometric Addition Formulas (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html) but others are to be simplified. In other words, I want to exclude addition formulas from the simplification process but I don't want to exclude other identities (such as cos^2 + sin^2 = 1 etc.).  For example let my expression will be;

cos(th_1)^2 + **2*cos(th_1)*cos(th_2) + 2*sin(th_1)*sin(th_2)**+ sin(th_1)^2

After some kind of "controlled simplification (?)" I want to get;

1 + 2*cos(th_1)*cos(th_2)  + 2*sin(th_1)*sin(th_2)

I don't want to get;

1 + 2*cos(th_1 - th_2)

I will use the bold terms' open forms.

I think I will need a clever usage of ExcludedForms, I've tried something but I couldn't do it.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `TrigExpand[]`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Please have a look at [the StackExchange editing-help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for improving your formatting in future postings. A useful post which answers many common questions can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users). Good Mathematica resources can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use underscore in a name

```
Format[th[n_]] := Subscript[th, n]

expr = Cos[th[1]]^2 + 2*Cos[th[1]]*Cos[th[2]] + 2*Sin[th[1]]*Sin[th[2]] + 
  Sin[th[1]]^2
```

[image]

As suggested by `Guess who it is`

```
expr // TrigExpand
```

[image]